# Execute plugin only if another execution succeeds

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have two executions of a plugin to run in two different phases.
For instance:

```xml
<executions>
   <execution>
        <id>A</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
   </execution>

   <execution>
        <id>B</id>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
   </execution>
</executions>
```

I want to execute B only if A succeeds. How do I do that?

Comment: About what kind of plugin are we talking about?

Comment: Do you want to fail the whole build if A does not succeed or do you want the build to continue, but only execute B if A succeeds?

Comment: gwhitake - I want to fail the build if A does not succeed.

khmarbaise - I'm trying to use the AntRun plugin to run an Ant Script with DbUnit task to: 
a-) insert data on the pre-integration-test phase
b-) delete data on the post-integration-test phase

However, I want to fail the build if I get a trouble on insert operation (so I don't execute the tests that rely on the inserted data to succeed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it using Antrun Maven plugin with the DELETE operations set to run on post-integration-test, INSERT operations set to run on pre-integration-test phase and using ant-contrib library. I've put the INSERT operations on a trycatch block. If an exception is caught, the DELETE operations are used and then I fail the build.

Here's a code example for the insertOperation.xml ant script (I won't put "project" and "target" tags, but "target" name is "dbunit-insert"):

```
// Classpath used is Maven's Test scope classpath    
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" 
         classpathref="maven.test.classpath"/>


// Classpath used is Maven's Test scope classpath
<taskdef name="dbunit" classname="org.dbunit.ant.DbUnitTask"
         classpathref="maven.test.classpath"/>

<trycatch>
    <try>
        <dbunit driver="your.driver" url="your.database.url" 
                userid="your.database.username" password="your.database.password"
                schema="your.database.schema">

            <operation type="INSERT" src="src/main/resources/insertYourDataSet.flat" 
                           format="flat"/> 

            // I know it has flat format as default but I define it so it won't
            // appear NULL on the console during the execution. And although
            // you can define the "transaction" parameter on "operation", it will 
            // only rollback the "operation" in which it is defined. This means
            // that if a second file is set for INSERT and you get a problem with it,
            // even setting the "transaction" parameter to "true" it won't rollback 
            // the first INSERT made.

        </dbunit>
    </try>
    <catch>

        // XML with DELETE operations
        // This XML was created based on the inserted data
        // e.g.: if you insert a String with "abc", this will delete it
        // This works as a rollback for ALL INSERT operations
        // So, if you get a trouble on a second file
        // it grants that the first inserted dataset will be deleted.
        <ant antfile="src/main/resources/ant/deleteOperation.xml" 
                inheritrefs="true"/>


        // This command will fail Maven build
        // print the message you've set and prevent it from running tests
        // that rely on the data you tried to insert

        <fail message="Failed build due to problem on an INSERT operation"/>
    </catch>
</trycatch>
```

And here's a code example for the deleteOperation.xml ant script (I won't put "project" and "target" tags, but "target" name is "dbunit-delete"):

```
// Notice that I don't need the ant-contrib library
// That's because DELETE operations are simply ignored if the data
// doesn't exist.
// You won't need a trycatch block, so no ant-contrib here
<taskdef name="dbunit" classname="org.dbunit.ant.DbUnitTask"/>


        <dbunit driver="your.driver" url="your.database.url" 
                userid="your.database.username" password="your.database.password"
                schema="your.database.schema">

            <operation type="DELETE" src="src/main/resources/deleteYourDataSet.flat" 
                           format="flat"/> 

        </dbunit>
```

Hope I help someone with this.